# nuxt.js call stack size render issue when login with IBM App Id

Tags: vue.js, runtime-error, nuxt.js, app-id, ibm-appid

I have a problem using IBM App Id and Nuxt.js project. When I am trying to do the signIn method from
IBM AppId, it thows an error, `error setAlgAndProvider hash alg set fail alg=sha256/RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

that's my code from my login component:

```
<template>
    <div class="login" @click="login">
        CLICK TO LOGIN
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "Login",
    data: () => ({
        appID: null
    }),
    mounted() {
        this.appID = new AppID();
        this.init();
    },
    methods: {
        async init() {
            await this.appID.init({
                clientId: '************',
                discoveryEndpoint: '********'
            });
        },
        async login() {
            const tokens = await this.appID.signin();
            console.log("***TOKENS***", tokens);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Any ideas? I see that error on my browser (attached image)

[image: error]

Comment: I'd go set a breakpoint on the `signIn` call, and **step in**. Hopefully you could go in the library source code, then you can check if it's more likely a problem with your call, or with the library.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this issue Julen? I get the same error